# Do We Sink or Swim?

Tags: code-golf

**The Problem**

A doomsday scenario is described by three numbers on a single line, `n`, `m`, and `p`. Following that line are `n` lines with `m` values per line. Each value represents the total units of water each cell can hold.

The following `p` lines describe the weather for the next `p` days. 1 unit of rain falls on a single cell each day. If the amount of water in a cell exceeds the amount it can hold, that cell floods. If multiple adjacent cells are at full capacity, they are treated as one cell that share common neighbors (think Minesweeper when you click on a group of blanks).

- A single middle cell has 4 neighbors
- Two adjacent, full capacity middle cells are treated as one cell that has 6 neighbors
- A single corner cell has 2 neighbors
- A single wall cell has 3 neighbors

When a cell floods, a flood event occurs. All excess water is evenly distributed to its neighbors. If that causes one or more neighbors to flood, then another flood event occurs. This continues until the water has settled, or the city has completely flooded.

**Example Input**

> 7 5 3 
>   3 2 3 4 5 
>   2 2 0 3 4 
>   1 1 2 3 3 
>   4 1 2 2 2 
>   4 1 1 2 2 
>   4 4 1 2 2 
>   4 4 2 2 2 
>   0 0 
>   1 2 
>   4 3

- `0 0` means it rained on row 1, col 1
- `1 2` means it rained on row 2, col 3 (which can hold zero water and immediately floods!)

After `p` days of rain, if the city is completely flooded, output **Sink**. Otherwise, output **Swim**.

**Example Output**

> Swim

**Assumptions**

- Input may be provided through stdin, read from "city.txt", or accepted as an argument. All three are allowed so as not to invalidate any answers already posted.
- Water capacities will be non-negative integers.

40+ teams of undergrad college students (from A&M, UT, LSU, Rice, Baylor, etc.) competing in a programming contest with a variety of languages available could not solve this problem in 5 hours. Because of that, I can't help but mention that there is a catch to this puzzle that makes the solution trivial. Shortest code still wins, because I am that confident that the shortest code will also solve the puzzle.

Comment: Is it `n` lines of `m` values or the other way around? Your example doesn't match the written specification.

Comment: @algorithmshark Corrected

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that you sink if the amount of rain is larger than the sum of rain that all the squares can hold; otherwise you float. Is this it?

Comment: @hosch250 Spoiling the fun!

Comment: I used to say "I sink, therefore I swim." Unfortunately, I'm now carrying enough fat that I no longer have negative buoyancy.

Comment: Yeah, you should have held off mentioning the shortcut. It's definitely facepalm-worthy if you missed it.

Comment: "The excess water is evenly distributed to its neighbors." - that is likely to be 1 unit of water. Does it distribute as e.g. `0.25` units to each adjacent cell (assuming a single middle flooded cell)?

Comment: OK, got it, that doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @NeilSlater 0.25 to each neighbor if they aren't already flooded and if it is a middle cell. If one neighbor is flooded, they are treated as one and the water is evenly distributed to ALL neighbors of both cells. For example, two adjacent flooded cells have 6 neighbors. A wall cell would distribute 0.3 repeating to each neighbor, and a corner would distribute 0.5.

Comment: @John: Thanks, got it. The trap is trying to run the described process as a simulation as opposed to spotting a key simplifying property of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Golfscript, <s>37</s> [30](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI3IDUgMwozIDIgMyA0IDUgCjIgMiAwIDMgNCAKMSAxIDIgMyAzIAo0IDEgMiAyIDIgCjQgMSAxIDIgMiAKNCA0IDEgMiAyIAo0IDQgMiAyIDIgMCAwIDEgMiA0IDMgIgp%2BXShcKEAqXChAQDx7K30qPiJTd2ltU2luayI0Lz0%3D) characters

New and improved, thanks to [PeterTaylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23259/do-we-sink-or-swim/23270#comment48415_23270) for tips:

```
~](\(@*\(@@<{+}*>"SwimSink"4/=
```

**Explanation**:

```
Code                     -                                            - Stack
~]                       - parse input into an array of integers      - []
(                        - pop first number and put on stack          - [] 7
\(                       - \ swaps top two, then pop first num again  - 7 [] 5
@                        - bring 3rd down from stack to front         - [] 5 7
*                        - mult. this is grid size                    - [] 35
\(@                      - bring next # out - the days of rain        - [] 3 35
@                        - bring array out                            - 3 35 []
<                        - take first 35 elements out of array.
                           this extracts just the capacities and 
                           consumes the rest                          - 3 []
{+}*                     - fold the array using plus - this sums the
                           entire thing                               - 3 86
<                        - greater-than comparison: 3 > 86?           - 0
"SwimSink"4/             - push a string and split it to groups of 4  - 0 ["Swim" "Sink"]

=                        - index into the array using the result of
                           the comparison. if rain > capacity, then
                           sink, else swim                            - "Swim"
```

Program then terminates, outputting the stack.

---

Old version + explanation:

```
[~](\(@*\(@{\(@\-}*\;0>"Sink""Swim"if
```

Same approach as [Fors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23263/4800), just Golfscripted =). Can likely be made more efficient. Input is from stdin.

**Explanation**:

```
Code                     -                                            - Stack
[~]                      - parse input into an array of integers      - []
(                        - pop first number and put on stack          - [] 7
\(                       - \ swaps top two, then pop first num again  - 7 [] 5
@                        - bring 3rd down from stack to front         - [] 5 7
*                        - mult. this is grid size                    - [] 35
\(@                      - bring next # out - the days of rain        - [] 3 35
{                        - define a block which...
 \(@                     - brings next number out
 \-                      - swaps and subtracts 2nd down from top
}                                                                     - [] 3 35 {}
*                        - repeat that block 35 times. this ends up
                           pulling the capacities out one by one
                           and decrementing our number-of-days 
                           number by each one                         - [] -84 
\;                       - swap and kill the array to get rid of
                           unused input                               - -84
0>"Sink""Swim"if         - if the num > 0, evaluate to "Sink", 
                           otherwise to "Swim"                        - "Swim"
```

Program then outputs the stack, which is just the answer.

Comment: `]` without a matching `[` will collect the entire stack into an array, so an initial `[~]` can be simplified to `~]`. To get the first `grid_size` elements of an array, use `<`, so `<{+}*` can almost certainly save you a bit on adding the total capacity. `0>"Sink""Swim"if` can be `0>"SinkSwim"4/=`

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks for the tips! Are you sure about `~]`? I tried it and it didn't seem to work. The last hack is nice though it has to be `"SwimSink"` - will use it. and the array thing also seems promising, will get to work on that.

Comment: I'm certain: that's a standard trick which I and others have been using for years.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Hmm strange. Try it in [the interpreter](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjcgNSAzCjMgMiAzIDQgNSAKMiAyIDAgMyA0IAoxIDEgMiAzIDMgCjQgMSAyIDIgMiAKNCAxIDEgMiAyIAo0IDQgMSAyIDIgCjQgNCAyIDIgMiAwIDAgMSAyIDQgMyAiCn5dKFwoQCpcKEBAPHsrfSo%2BIlN3aW1TaW5rIjQvPQ%3D%3D) I linked to - it fails. Then - ok maybe the web interpreter is non-standard. But I tried also with `ruby golfscript.rb` and it still didn't work... can you verify that it works on your end? I get same error on both: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: When you insert a string literal to substitute for lack of stdin, you should precede it with a semicolon to remove the empty string which actually comes "from stdin". [With that it works fine](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI3IDUgMwozIDIgMyA0IDUgCjIgMiAwIDMgNCAKMSAxIDIgMyAzIAo0IDEgMiAyIDIgCjQgMSAxIDIgMiAKNCA0IDEgMiAyIAo0IDQgMiAyIDIgMCAwIDEgMiA0IDMgIgp%2BXShcKEAqXChAQDx7K30qPiJTd2ltU2luayI0Lz0%3D)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Oh awesome! Thanks. Another niche of this neat little language - learned.

Answer (score 20):

## C: <s>100</s> <s>96</s> 95 characters

```c
n,m;main(p){scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&p);for(n*=m;n--;scanf("%d",&m))p-=m;puts(p>0?"Sink":"Swim");}
```

Five hours? Took me five minutes. :)

Aragaer, thank you for the simplifications! I did however rearrange the variable declarations and arguments to main, seeing as Clang throws an error if the second argument to main is of any other type than `char **`.

Comment: 96 - `p;main(n,m){for(scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&p),n*=m;n--;scanf("%d",&m),p-=m);puts(p>0?"Sink":"Swim");}`

Comment: 95 - `n,m;main(p){for(scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&p),n*=m;n--;scanf("%d",&m))p-=m;puts(p>0?"Sink":"Swim");}`. I've also played with idea of `n-=scanf`, but not sure if program will be correct after that. First `scanf` can be moved to the front of `for` without changing the character count.

Comment: `n-=scanf...` wouldn't work, as `n-=1` basically is a pre-increment, so it would miss the south-eastern corner. The other change is great.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 4 lines, 175 characters

```
import sys 
F=sys.stdin
n,m,p=[int(a) for a in F.readline().split()]
print("sink") if p > sum([sum(int(x) for x in F.readline().split()) for a in range(n)]) else print("swim")
```

Lol, I wonder if the 40+ teams ended up finding the catch... after working it out the hard way.

Comment: I was on one of the 40+ teams. We were GIVEN the catch after failing. Everyone in the auditorium facepalmed simultaneously. I think perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned it here. You guys were too quick!

Comment: Ouch!  By the way, should I get the input from stdin for these sort of questions? - I'm new to stackexchange. :)

Comment: I was going to edit my question to say specify STDIN, but I feared that it would invalidate your answer. I have been reading puzzles here for about a month, and haven't really noticed if people specified STDIN or not.

Comment: Edited answer to use stdin - golfed it more anyway! :)

Comment: @swalladge Welcome to Codegolf! I recommend making the headline a headline by prepending a `#`.

Comment: You can bring it down to 108 if you use `input()` and `map()`: `n,_,p=map(int,input().split());print(['sink','swim'][p>sum(sum(map(int,input().split()))for a in range(n))])`

Comment: Didn't think of map - can get it down to 3 lines, 149 chars with your method but still using stdin: `import sys 
n,m,p=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
print(["swim","sink"][p>sum([sum(map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())) for a in range(n)])])`

Answer (score 6):

## J (50 char) and K (40) double feature

Turns out, as usual, these two have the exact same structure in their solutions, so they're both here. K is a whole lot shorter, though, which is a pleasant surprise.

```
>Sink`Swim{~(]<[:+/[+/@".@$+1!:1@#1:)/0 2{".1!:1]1
```

Explanation:

- `".1!:1]1` - Read in the first line, and convert to integers.
- `(...)/0 2{` - Take the items at index 0 and 2 (`n` and `p` respectively), and use them as the left and right arguments to the verb `(...)`, respectively.
- `+1!:1@#1:` - Read in `n+p` lines.
- `[+/@".@$` - Take (`$`) the first `n` rows (`[`), discarding the rest, and then convert to integers (`".`) and sum on each row (`+/`).
- `]<[:+/` - Add together the row sums, and then compare this value to the right argument, `p`. We produce true if `p` is less than the sum.
- `` >Sink`Swim{~ `` - Select `Swim` if the above comprasion resulted in true, or `Sink` if false.

Usage:

```
   >Sink`Swim{~(]<[:+/[+/@".@$+1!:1@#1:)/0 2{".1!:1]1
7 5 3
3 2 3 4 5
2 0 3 3 4
1 1 2 3 3
4 1 2 2 2
4 1 1 2 2
4 4 1 2 2
4 4 2 2 2
0 0
1 2
4 3
Swim
```

And now the K:

```
`Sink`Swim@{z<+//.:'x#0::'(x+z)#`}.. 0:`
```

Explained:

- `` . 0:` `` - Read in a line of input, and convert to an array of integers.
- `{...}.` - Use these three numbers `n m p` as the arguments `x y z` to this function.
- `` 0::'(x+z)#` `` - Create `x+z` copies of the input file handle `` ` ``, and then read in a line for each of them (`0::'`).
- `.:'x#` - Take the first `x` items, and convert each to a vector of numbers.
- `z<+//` - Sum the entire matrix together, and then test to see if it is greater than `z`.
- `` `Sink`Swim@ `` - Return `Sink` or `Swim` according to whether the test returned true.

Usage:

```
  `Sink`Swim@{z<+//.:'x#0::'(x+z)#`}.. 0:`
7 5 3
3 2 3 4 5
2 2 0 3 4
1 1 2 3 3
4 1 2 2 2
4 1 1 2 2
4 4 1 2 2
4 4 2 2 2
0 0
1 2
4 3
`Swim
```

Answer (score 6):

### APL,  35

```
4↑'SwimSink'⌽⍨4×x[3]>+/{+/⎕}¨⍳1⌷x←⎕
```

Not sure if allowed but it stops accepting input after the "city"

`x←⎕` Takes input and store it in variable `x` (space-delimited numbers are interpreted as a numerical array)
`1⌷` Extract index 1 (APL arrays are one-based)
`⍳` Generate an array from 1 to the argument (`1⌷x←⎕` in this case)
`¨` "Map" operation
`{+/⎕}` Take array from input and return the sum
`+/` Sum the array generated by the map operation
`4×x[3]>` Test if the sum < `x[3]` (returns 1 or 0), then multiply 4
`'SwimSink'⌽⍨` Rotate the string `'SwimSink'` by that amount
`4↑` Finally, extract the first 4 characters of the string

Comment: I think the only part that matters is that it outputs the correct answer for any given input. If this is unusual for CodeGolf, hopefully someone will let me know.

Comment: Change `⎕IO←0`, then replace `4↑'SwimSink'⌽⍨4×` with `'Swim' 'Sink'⊃⍨`, `x[3]` with `x[2]`, and `1⌷x` with `⊃x` to save two bytes.

Comment: @Rainbolt : this entry is 53 bytes long - measuring by `utf-8` chars makes this one "appear" more compact when it fact it takes more space than the best entries for `J+K` above - `J` is 50 bytes worth of `ASCII`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Why are you telling me this? Did I post a leaderboard somewhere?

Comment: @Rainbolt : you're OP right ? so I presumed, apparently inaccurately, that you might have a say regarding the challenge/contest you posted

Answer (score 6):

## AWK, 70

```
n{for(;NF;NF--)s+=$NF;n--}NR==1{n=$1;p=$3}END{print p<s?"Swim":"Sink"}
```

This is an imrovement by laindir on my submission (86):

```
NR==1{h=$1;w=$2;r=$3;next}NR<=h{for(i=1;i<=w;++i)c+=$i}END{print(c>r?"Swim":"Sink")}
```

Comment: `NR<=h` should be `NR<=h+1`, otherwise you'll get false Sinks as the last line of capacities is skipped. This can also be shortened to 70 as `n{for(;NF;NF--)s+=$NF;n--}NR==1{n=$1;p=$3}END{print p<s?"Swim":"Sink"}`

Comment: @laindir Well, thank you very much for the improvement! I find it so fun, that Awk just comes next to APL, J and K, which were breeded to beat everyone on code-golfing! :-)

Comment: @user40989 I don't understand. Awk seem 40-100% longer than J/K/APL, even though they are not golfing languages, but rather (stem from) commercial programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

## CoffeeScript - <strike>128</strike> 113

A function that takes the string as the only argument:

```
s=(l)->l=l.split /\n/;[n,m,p]=l[x=0].split /\s/;x+=c|0 for c in r.split /\s/ for r in l[1..n];`p>x?"Sink":"Swim"`
```

Comment: You can remove the indentation, and move everything on first line separated by semicolons. You also write `\`p>x?"Sink":"Swim"\`` instead of `if p>x then"Sink"else"Swim"`. Parens for the third statement also aren't needed.

Answer (score 4):

## SED, 128

It was fun to write a `sed` version of this.  It has the following
short-comings:

- It assumes the city has more than two columns, to easily recognise
  rain lines.
- It assumes that the capacity of each city is in the range 0-9.

Here it is:

```
1d
s/^. .$/R/
G
:a
s/[\n 0]//
/[2-9]/{s/^/C/
y/23456789/12345678/}
s/1/C/
s/0//
s/RC//
h
ta
${s/R//g
s/^Sink//
s/.*C$/Swim/
p}
```

Call with the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 3):

## SWI-Prolog 79

If you don't mind the fact that this answer takes input by query, rather than via stdin:

```
s(A,L):-append(A,B),sumlist(B,C),length(L,D),(D>C->E='Sink';E='Swim'),print(E).
```

The answer doesn't validate input format, but I don't think it is a problem, since programming contest also doesn't require you to do so.

Sample query (using example in the question):

```
s([[3,2,3,4,5],
   [2,2,0,3,4],
   [1,1,2,3,3],
   [4,1,2,2,2],
   [4,1,1,2,2],
   [4,4,1,2,2],
   [4,4,2,2,2]],
  [(0,0),
   (1,2),
   (4,3)]).
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 152

```
import numpy
n, m, p = map(int,raw_input('').split())
print 'swim' if p<numpy.sum(numpy.matrix(';'.join([raw_input('') for i in range(n)]))) else 'sink'
```

Comment: You could start by taking out some whitespace. After `,`, before and after `'`, after `)`…

Answer (score 1):

## Scala - 128

```
val a=readLine.split(' ')map(_.toInt);println(if((1 to a(0)map(x=>readLine.split(' ')map(_.toInt)sum)sum)>a(2))"swim"else"sink")
```

It might be possible to omit some parentheses or something but Scala is really fickle about punctuation and point-free style and () vs {} and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript - 73 Characters

```
for(i=c=0,a=s.split(/\s/);i++<a[0]*a[1];)c+=a[2+i]*1;c>a[2]?"Swim":"Sink"
```

Assumes the input is in the variable `s` and outputs `Swim` or `Sink`.

**Example:**

From the original question - entering this into the browser console:

```
s="7 5 3\n3 2 3 4 5\n2 2 0 3 4\n1 1 2 3 3\n4 1 2 2 2\n4 1 1 2 2\n4 4 1 2 2\n4 4 2 2 2\n0 0\n1 2\n4 3";
for(i=c=0,a=s.split(/\s/);i++<a[0]*a[1];)c+=a[2+i]*1;c>a[2]?"Swim":"Sink"
```

Outputs:

```
Swim
```