# Draw an ASCII Lightning Bolt

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Introduction

Partly inspired by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640309/how-to-create-a-lightning-bolt-design-using-css), let's draw an ASCII Lightning Bolt.

Write a program that takes a positive Integer `n` via STDIN or command line and outputs the ASCII Lightning Bolt below.

**Input**

Positive Integer `n` representing the number of lightning zig-zag tiers to draw.

**Example Output**

n=1

```
__
\ \
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

n=2

```
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

n=3

```
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

n=4

```
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

.
.
.
etc

---

**Additional notes**

- You may write a function that takes `n` as the only argument and
  prints or returns the string.
- Trailing spaces and new lines are okay.
- No leading spaces except where appropriate for the designated
  pattern.
- **Shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: How many of those challenges have we seen so far?

Comment: @flawr Too many 

Answer (score 19):

## Java, <s>201</s> <s>196</s> <s>189</s> <s>186</s> 182 bytes

Obviously not the best, but it *is* in Java.

```java
class I{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(("__\na a"+new String(new byte[new Byte(a[0])-1]).replace("\0","__a\\  __\\\n a")+"  a   \\/").replace("a","\\ \\\n"));}}
```

Comment: Ah, Java, the language where you've already lost before you start typing the body of your `main` method.

Comment: I do sometimes think that the `main` shouldn't count towards byte count, and a few languages that have verbose keywords should maybe be allowed macros. Then it'd be interesting

Comment: @AlecTeal Totally agree, some questions actually specify that they only require functional snippets, but most do not.

Comment: *You may write a function that takes n as the only argument and prints or returns the string.* So, umm, you should probably do that ;)

Comment: It may be 6 months late, but http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/42736 or using a function make it shorter.

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 41 bytes

```
":¡ö cQïO[nu÷&,"255b6b"
 _\/X"f='X/~ri(*\
```

I can probably squeeze a few more bytes out, but here's some compression. I picked a base which would lead to no unprintables.

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%3A%C2%A1%C3%B6%20cQ%C3%AFO%5Bnu%C3%B7%26%2C%22255b6b%22%0A%20_%5C%2FX%22f%3D'X%2F~ri%28*%5C&input=2).

The lightning bolt is split into `top + middle * (input-1) + bottom`, where `top`, `middle`, `bottom` (compressed using base conversion) are

```
__
\. 

  \
.\.\
__\.\
\..__ 

    \
.\.\
..\.\
...\/
```

*(Spaces are marked with `.`s)*

### 40 bytes

Thanks to [Optimizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31414/optimizer)

```
"¹Ñ³Û-+ÎDx^áÐ"254b6b"
_\ 0/"f=)/~ri(*\
```

Comment: [40](http://goo.gl/nmDEm7)

Comment: thanks for the explanation with `top + middle * (input-1) + bottom`, it reminded me that powershell could multiply strings :P

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 76

Using template string, the 3 newlines are significant and counted.

Test running the snippet (Firefox only)

```js
f=n=>`__
1 1${`__1\\  __\\
 1`.repeat(n-1)}  1   \\/`.replace(/1/g,`\\ \\
`)

// TEST

go=_=>O.innerHTML=f(I.value)

go()
```

```html
N: <input id=I value=3><button onclick='go()'>Test</button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell, <strike>72</strike> 63 bytes

Stupid Windows and your \r\n... This could have been <strike>67</strike> 59 bytes!

```
%{$a="\ \
";"__
$a"+" $a`__$a\  __\
"*($_-1)+" $a  $a   \/"}
```

Comment: For code golf, I think \r\n still counts as \n, since it does the same thing

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <strike>60</strike> 54 bytes (Thanks @isaacg)

My first attempt at Pyth, probably very bad.

```
"__
\ \ "VtQ" \ \ 
__\ \ 
\  __\ ")" \ \ 
  \ \ 
   \/
```

[Verify it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%22__%0A%5C+%5C+%22VtQ%22+%5C+%5C+%0A__%5C+%5C+%0A%5C++__%5C+%22)%22+%5C+%5C+%0A++%5C+%5C+%0A+++%5C%2F&input=3&debug=0).

Comment: Welcome to Pyth! By the way, Pyth allows literal newlines in its strings, which would be 1 character shorter than `\n`. Also, the first `\\ `in the program could be just a `\ `.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP - <s>84 79</s> 78 bytes

```
<?php
define('N',3); // <- didnt count these bytes as TS said I could take var N as input
?>
<?="__
\ \
 \ \ ".str_repeat("
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \ ",N-1)."
  \ \ 
   \/"
```

View the result source or wrap in `<pre />` to check results. The newlines are required in the code.
The -1 could be moved to the `define`, but I considered that a cheat.

1st improvement: replace `\n` with actual newlines
2nd: Since I can define a var, I used a CONTANT, safes the `$`. +an unneeded space in str_repeat
3rd: Accidentally removed the -1, but saved a byte by using `<?=` instead of echo.

Answer (score 5):

### ><> (Fish), 409 bytes

Run by `fish.py bolt.fish --value n` where `bolt.fish` is the program name and `n` is your positive integer input.

```
\
\         "__"       a
\         "\ \"      a
\         " \ \"     a
\r1-:?!vr "__\ \"    a
\     !0  "\  __\"   a
\     !6  " \ \"  a04.
>r   9a.  "__\ \"    \
      /   "\  __\"  \ 
       /  " \ \"   \  
        / "  \ \" \   
         /"   \/"\    
                 aaaaa
|o|!~r           /    
         \        /   
        \          /  
       \            / 
      \              /
```

It's not short, but it looks cool. My attempt was to try to make it look like a lightning strike. Also, it always errors on completion.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, 50 bytes

```
"__
\ \
"q~(" \ \
__\ \
\  __\
"*" \ \
"_S\"   \/"
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22__%0A%5C%20%5C%0A%22q~%28%22%20%5C%20%5C%0A__%5C%20%5C%0A%5C%20%20__%5C%0A%22*%22%20%5C%20%5C%0A%22_S%5C%22%20%20%20%5C%2F%22&input=3)

Answer (score 4):

### Brainfuck, 164 bytes

```
,<++++++++++++++++[>--->+>++++++>++>++++++>+++<<<<<<-]>->--->---->>->-<..<<<.>.>
.<.<.>>.<.>.<.<.<[>>>>..<<.>.<.<.>.>..>..<<.<.>>.<.>.<.<.<-]>>>..<.>.<.<.>>...<.
>>>.
```

With comments:

```
Initialise n and character set with i as counter
Memory = in♪\ _/
,<++++++++++++++++[>--->+>++++++>++>++++++>+++<<<<<<-]>->--->---->>->-

Draw top of lightning bolt
<..<<<.>.>.<.<.>>.<.>.<.<.<

Draw lightning bolt zigzags
[>>>>..<<.>.<.<.>.>..>..<<.<.>>.<.>.<.<.<-]

Draw lightning bolt tip
>>>..<.>.<.<.>>...<.>>>.
```

Okay, how this Brainfuck answer beating Java and C#?

Comment: Woah, nice golfing, especially in BF!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 69+1

69 characters, plus 1 for the `-n` command line switch to fetch input from stdin.

```Perl
$s="\\ \\$/";print"__$/$s $s".("__$s\\  __\\$/ $s"x--$_)."  $s   \\/"
```

#### Usage example:

```
perl -ne '$s="\\ \\$/";print"__$/$s $s".("__$s\\  __\\$/ $s"x--$_)."  $s   \\/"' <<<"2"
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

Comment: Some improvements possible: `perl -pe'$_="__\ns s"."__s\\  __\\\n s"x--$_."  s   \\/";s!s!\\ \\\n!g'`. Also `\n` can be replaced with a literal line break for another 3 character saved.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), 86

Not gonna win, but I love 1-line solution and I hate slashes.

```js
f=n=>atob("X18KXCBc"+"CiBcIFwKX19cIFwKXCAgX19c".repeat(n-1)+"CiBcIFwKICBcIFwKICAgXC8")
```

Comment: Cool!  What it is doing?

Comment: @rpax I used base64 encoding to avoid \\ and \n . Have a look at `atob` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 101 bytes

My not so original implementation in c

```c
f(n){puts("__\n\\ \\");for(;--n;puts(" \\ \\\n__\\ \\\n\\  __\\"));puts(" \\ \\\n  \\ \\\n   \\/");}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 166 bytes

```
class I{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write(("__\na a"+"".PadLeft(int.Parse(a[0])-1).Replace(" ",@"__a\  __\
 a")+@"  a   \/").Replace("a",@"\ \
"));}}
```

**EDIT 1:** improved the result from 186B to 173B
**EDIT 2:** saved 1B by using `PadLeft` instead of `PadRight`
**EDIT 3:** saved 8B by dropping `PadLeft`'s second parameter and using verbatim string literals

Comment: Nice... You can do away with the `public` at the start, and instead of using a char array, you can use [`String.PadRight(int, char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx), which is shorter and will let you use an ascii char which doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Some tweaks:
* drop the second parameter to PadLeft(); it's implied (-4)
* change 2 of the strings to verbatim (the OP says newlines are fine, and we only need \n, not full \r\n, so -4)

End result:

class I{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write(("__\na a"+"".PadLeft(int.Parse(a[0])-1).Replace(" ",@"__a\  __\
 a")+"  a   \\/").Replace("a",@"\ \
"));}}

[I can't display newlines in comments, but you can edit the original answer!]

Comment: Nice tips, it was hard to verbatim formatting in order :)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 221 Bytes

```
class C{static void Main(string[]n){int e=System.Int32.Parse(n[0]);var o=@"__{0}\ \{0} \ \{0}";while(e>1){o+=@"__\ \{0}\  __\{0} \ \{0}";e--;}System.Console.WriteLine(o + @"  \ \{0}   \/{0}",System.Environment.NewLine);}}
```

This isn't the best, or the smallest answer, but I figured I'd give it a try.
[Fsacer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51284/draw-an-ascii-lightning-bolt/51322#51322) is much shorter and I think you should check it out.
I just decided to do this just as an alternative method really.

Comment: Hey, here I easily dropped it to 182B. Code: `class C{static void Main(string[]n){var e=int.Parse(n[0]);var o=@"__{0}\ \{0} \ \{0}";while(e-->1){o+=@"__\ \{0}\  __\{0} \ \{0}";}System.Console.Write(o+@"  \ \{0}   \/{0}","\n");}}`

Comment: Nice, and just curious, but why did you change the type of e from int to var? It's still 3 characters :P

Comment: No reason, maybe because I love var keyword :)

Answer (score 3):

## Awk, 101+8 bytes

101 characters, plus 8 for `-v n=$1` to get integer from shell.

```
'{l="\\ \\";print"__\n"l"\n "l;for(i=1;i<n;++i)print"__"l"\n\\  __\\\n "l}END{print"  "l"\n   \\/"}'
```

New to this SE site, [unclear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/tips-for-golfing-in-awk) if those parameters should count.

#### Ungolfed

```
awk 
-v n=$1
'{
  l="\\ \\";
  print "__\n"l"\n "l;
  for(i=1; i<n; ++i)
    print "__"l"\n\\  __\\\n "l
}
END
{
  print "  "l"\n   \\/"
}'
```

#### Usage example:

```
lightning() { echo | awk -v n=$1 '{l="\\ \\";print"__\n"l"\n "l;for(i=1;i<n;++i)print"__"l"\n\\  __\\\n "l}END{print"  "l"\n   \\/"}'; }
lightning 3
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

Comment: [Here is the consensus on counting command-line flags.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/8478) So I think you've done that right.

Comment: Let's formulate it as “_calculated_ that right”, because definitely not _done_ right. If the variable assignment is put after the code, there is no need for the `-v ` part. Not mentioning that the whole variable idea is unnecessary, just like the separate `END` block. 89 characters: `{l="\\ \\";print"__\n"l"\n "l;for(;--$1;)print"__"l"\n\\  __\\\n "l;print"  "l"\n   \\/"}` http://pastebin.com/NCznF9kH

Answer (score 3):

## Python <strike>97</strike> <strike>82</strike> 78char:

```
print(("__\nl l"+"__l\  __\\\n l"*~-input()+"  l   \/").replace('l','\ \\\n'))
```

This is my first code golf

## @(^_^)@

Test here

Comment: This is python 3? Will that input() work for integers?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>126</s> <s>118</s> 117 bytes

Just something to get us started with.

```python
n=int(input())
p=print
p('__\n\\ \\')
for i in[0]*~-n:p(r''' \ \
__\ \
\  __\
''',end='')
p(r''' \ \
  \ \
   \/
''')
```

Comment: If you don't need the loop variable, you can iterate trough `[0]*(n-1)` to get `n-1` iterations. You can also write `(n-1)` as `~-n`.

Comment: You can save one byte by changing `i in [0]` to `i in[0]`.

Comment: Welcome! A single line print in the loop is also shorter: `for i in[0]*~-n:p(' \\ \\\n__\\ \\\n\\  __\\')`.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>119</s> 108 bytes

```
p(t){for(;t;t/=4)putchar(" \\_\n"[t%4]);}main(c){for(p(13434);p(836),--c;p(57154842));p(265488);puts("/");}
```

## First attempt, 150 bytes

```
v(a){putchar(a);}s(b){b--?v(32),s(b):v(92);}l(b){s(b);s(1);v(10);}main(c){for(puts("__\n\\ \\");l(1),--c;puts("__\\ \\\n\\  __\\"));l(2);s(3);v(47);}
```

`main` is accepting an int argument, so run like this: `./lightning . . .` to pass `4` as argument.

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Ao0SzOi2/SMO6xLpE39ZEs6AoM68kTcNHSSEmJj4mT0m7RNVE07o2NzEzTyMZorRAQ92kSl3TukDDwthMU0dXNxnINDU3NDWxMDHSBIkbmQHZFkBWaUmxhpK@EtCA////6wEA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 76 bytes

```py
print'__\n\ \\\n \ \\\n'+r'''__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
'''*~-input()+'  \ \\\n   \/'
```

Just print the first three lines, then print the next three lines `n-1` times, and then print the final 2 lines. All in one go.

And here is a nice try at an alternative that (unfortunately) uses exactly the same number of bytes:

```py
print('__\n| |'+'__|\  __\\\n |'*~-input()+'  |   \/').replace('|','\ \\\n')
```

Comment: Have you tried using %s formatting for the middle part?

Comment: @Sp3000 I need braces around it to make it work with the `*`, that gives me 77 bytes - or not inlining it, but that costs 79 bytes. :(

Answer (score 2):

### F#, 98 characters, 105 bytes

```
let l n=(@"__♪◙\z"+String.replicate(n-1)@" \z__\z\  __\♪◙"+ @" \z  \z   \/").Replace("z"," \\\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal: <s>149</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> 137 characters

```pascal
var n:Word;begin
Read(n);Writeln('__'#10'\ \'#10' \ \');for n:=2to n do Writeln('__\ \'#10'\  __\'#10' \ \');Write('  \ \'#10'   \/')end.
```

After all, Pascal's only golfing strength is that backslashes need no escaping…

Comment: `for n:=2 to n do` also works.

Comment: Thank you, @randomra. I think was ~18 years ago when I was aware of this possibility… Nice to remember it.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam 54 Chars

not the shortest, but since i started CJam today, im happy with it.

```
rd(:T;{'__}:W~N{'\:XSXN}:V~SV{WVXSSWXNSV;N}T*SSVSSSX'/
```

[Try it](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rd(%3AT%3B%7B'__%7D%3AW~N%7B'%5C%3AXSXN%7D%3AV~SV%7BWVXSSWXNSV%3BN%7DT*SSVSSSX'%2F&input=2)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 60 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the calling cell.

```gs
="__
\ \
 \ \
"&REPT("__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
",A1-1)&"  \ \
   \/
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 58 + 1 (`-n`) = 59 bytes

```perl
say'__
\ \
 \ \ 
'.'__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
'x--$_.'  \ \
   \/'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVI9Pp4rRiGGSwFIKHCp6wH5IG6MggKQARblUq/Q1VWJ11NXAPMUgJS@@v//Fv/yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoZGBr8180DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - <strike>135</strike> 104 bytes

The apostrophe in PRINT statements moves cursor to a new line.

SpecBAS lets you incorporate ASCII characters in a string via way of `#n`, so have built in some carriage returns (ASCII 13).

Built a string up using carriage returns and other characters, then used `REP$` to repeat it the required number of times.

```
1 LET b$="\ \": INPUT n: PRINT "__"'b$+REP$(#13" "+b$+#13"__"+b$+#13"\  __\",n-1)'" ";b$'"  ";b$'"   \/"
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 155

```
$l=PHP_EOL;echo$l;echo "__$l";for($i=0;$i<$argv[1];$i++){if($i>=1)echo "__\\ \\$l\\  __\\$l";else echo "\\ \\$l";echo " \\ \\$l";}echo "  \\ \\$l   \\/$l";
```

Ungolfed Version

```
$n = $argv[1];

echo PHP_EOL;
echo '__'.PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
    if($i>=1) {
        echo '__\\ \\'.PHP_EOL.'\\  __\\'.PHP_EOL;
        
    }
    else
    {
        echo '\\ \\'.PHP_EOL;
    }   
    echo ' \\ \\'.PHP_EOL; 
    
        
}    
echo '  \\ \\'.PHP_EOL;
echo '   \\/';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Your code can be further improved, got it down to 121 bytes. `echo$l=PHP_EOL,"__$l";$g="\\ \\$l";for($i=0;$i<$argv[1];$i++){echo($i?"__$g\\  __\\$l":$g)," $g";}echo"  $g",'   \\/',$l;`

Comment: In addition: remove the `$i=0`; remove the brackets for the `for` loop; increment the counter inside the loop (`echo($i++?"…`).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>183</s> 180 bytes

```
class L{public static void main(String[]a){String b="__\n\\ \\\n \\ \\\n";for(int i=1;i<new Long(a[0]);++i)b+="__\\ \\\n\\  __\\\n \\ \\\n";System.out.print(b+"  \\ \\\n   \\/");}}
```

## Lua, 110 bytes

```
function l(n)print("__\n\\ \\\n \\ \\\n"..string.rep("__\\ \\\n\\  __\\\n \\ \\\n",n-1).."  \\ \\\n   \\/")end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 46 bytes

```
.+
__#r r$0x  r   \/
1x

1
__r\  __\# r
r
\ \#
```

Takes input as unary.

Each line should go to its own file and `#` should be changed to newline in the files. This is impractical but you can run the code as is, as one file, with the `-s` flag, keeping the `#` markers. You can change the `#`'s to newlines in the output for readability if you wish. E.g.:

```
> echo -n 11|retina -s lightning|tr # '\n'
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

The algorithm is very simple. The pairs of lines (regex - substitute pairs) do the following substitution steps:

- Surround input with the top and bottom of the lightning.
- Subtract `1` from the unary input.
- Change every unary digit into the middle part of the lightning.
- Decompress the compressed `\ \` parts of the lightning to get the desired output.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@nzaWiBSLj4w9tK1IoUlGrUFAoUlBQiNHnMqzg4jIEShTFKCjEx8cc2qZQxFXEFaMAZP3/bwwA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online") (includes decimal conversion) but I was able to do it in 45 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@nzaWi9d@QK0ZBIT4@5tA2haL4@CKuOD3tQ9u44uMPbSsCkkUqXAoKRQoKCjH6XEVAlUBl//8bAwA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online") (includes decimal conversion).

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 59 bytes

```
'__
\ \'
,' \ \
__\ \
\  __\'*--$args[0]
' \ \
  \ \
   \/'
```

Test script:

```
$f = {

'__
\ \'
,' \ \
__\ \
\  __\'*--$args[0]
' \ \
  \ \
   \/'

}

&$f 1
&$f 2
&$f 3
&$f 4
```

Output:

```
__
\ \
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
__
\ \
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
__\ \
\  __\
 \ \
  \ \
   \/
```

Explanation:

This script is traditional `top`+`middle`+`bottom`. There is only one smart thing: the comma before the middle string force to repeat an array element rather than a string. Therefore, each `middle` is displayed on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

#### x86_16 machine code - 84 bytes

```
8B CB      MOV CX, BX
49         DEC CX          
B4 09      MOV AH, 09H   
        HEAD:
BA 02 01   MOV DX, OFFSET LIGHTNING_HEAD
CD 21      INT 21H
85 C9      TEST CX, CX   
74 09      JE TAIL
        BODY:
BA 1F 01   MOV DX, OFFSET LIGHTNING_LOOP_STR
CD 21      INT 21H
E3 02      JCXZ TAIL
E2 F7      LOOP BODY     
        TAIL:
BA 12 01   MOV DX, OFFSET LIGHTNING_TAIL
CD 21      INT 21H
B8 00 4C   MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21      INT 21H       

LIGHTNING_HEAD      DB 05FH, 05FH, 00AH, 00DH, 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 020H
                    DB 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 024H
LIGHTNING_TAIL      DB 020H, 020H, 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 020H, 020H, 020H
                    DB 05CH, 02FH, 024H
LIGHTNING_LOOP_STR  DB 05FH, 05FH, 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 05CH, 020H, 020H
                    DB 05FH, 05FH, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 020H, 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH
                    DB 00DH, 024H
```

Tested using DOSBox

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.1.2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.1.2.3), 144 bytes

```
func main:
in ""
conv i32
pop $a
push "__\n\\ \\\n \\ \\\n"
push "__\\ \\\n\\  __\\\n \\ \\\n"
dec $a
push $a
mul
add
push "  \\ \\\n   \\/"
add
print
ret
end
```

**Commented:**

```
func main:
    ; Get the input, convert it to an integer then store it in the accumulator
    in ""
    conv i32
    pop $a

    ; Push the first section of the lightning bolt
    push "__\n\\ \\\n \\ \\\n"

    ; Duplicate the middle section of the lightning bolt
    push "__\\ \\\n\\  __\\\n \\ \\\n"
    dec $a
    push $a
    mul

    ; Append the duplicated sections
    add

    ; Append the third section of the lightning bolt
    push "  \\ \\\n   \\/"
    add

    ; Print the result
    print
    ret
end
```