# My Squiggly Lamp

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

While moving, I broke my lamp. Now, I need a new one. It's your job to make me a lamp! I'm not sure what size I want, though I know I want a squiggly one.

Your program/function must take in a number input, and print out a lamp with that many squiggles/bumps.

**Examples:**

Input:`2`

Output:

```
/--\
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Input:`3`

Output:

```
/--\
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Input:`5`

Output:

```
/--\
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

**Rules:**

- 0 & negative numbers don't matter
- To give the lamps (an this challenge) more of a variety, you **must** change the lamp shade.

  - They must be **4** characters wide and **1** character high.
  - They can be in any shape, including non-lamp-shade shapes.
  - They must not contain whitespace.
  - The base must stay the same.
- You must show an example input & output with your lamp shade.
- Shortest code wins!

Comment: But it doesn't squiggle at all!. Would have loved if inputs > 5 made it squiggle.

Comment: @Optimizer I think "bumpy" would be a better word for it, but "squiggly" sounds fun :3

Comment: Does space count as a character for lamp shade ?

Comment: @Optimizer No, forgot to add that in.

Comment: Wait do I have to change the shade per input, or just make it different from the input?

Comment: @Maltysen The shade must be different from the examples provided, and must stay the same between inputs.

Comment: I downvoted. I think this is a boring ASCII art. There's a repeated section in the middle and no overlap between the parts, which are also too short to compress. It just has form `ABBB..BBBC`. The requirement to change a section just means people will use a short built-in string.

Comment: You can all stop downvoting already! I think OP got the message.

Comment: @xnor I feel sorry for the poor guy. This is probably one of the most downvoted questions ever :/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4A7X.jpg

Comment: @BetaDecay ;__;

Comment: Not voted in any way myself, but given the similarity with [Draw an ASCII Lightning Bolt](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51284/draw-an-ascii-lightning-bolt), I can understand the downvoters. Some little twist like having larger base for higher lamp, or having a repeated decoration only on each nth squiggle would made it a little bit different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth - 16 bytes

Uses quotes for the shade since N is preinitialized to that.

```
*N4VQ+d`();"/__\
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*N4VQ%2Bd%60()%3B%22%2F__%5C&input=5&debug=0).

```
* 4            String repetition 4x, implicit print
 N             Preinitialized to Quote
VQ             For N in range(Q)
 +             String concat
  d            Space
   `()         Repr of empty tuple
;              Close for loop
"/__\          Implicitly print string, implicit close quote
```

Sample for 5:

```
""""
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Snowman 0.2.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v0.2.0-alpha), 42 chars

```
)vg10sB]"[--]
"sP:" ()
"sP;bR"/__"sP92wRsP
```

Sample run:

```
llama@llama:...Code/snowman/ppcg53483lamp$ snowman lamp.snowman
5
[--]
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

So I only noticed that I forgot to implement the ability to escape backslashes within strings when I solved this challenge. That's definitely going to be a thing in the next version, but for now, here's what I did to print the final line:

```
"/__"sP92wRsP
```

`92` is the ASCII code for a backslash, `wR` wraps it in an array, and I can now print it with `sP` because "strings" in Snowman are actually just arrays of numbers.

Comment: Do you want to build a snow lamp?

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
"\__/"aiv
"&-1v!?:<&a" ()
~"!_\
?!;o>l
```

Input via a code point, e.g. space is 32. This uses part of the program's own code as the lampshade, resulting in something that looks like a satellite dish:

```
~\_!
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

*(Suggestion thanks to @randomra)*

For three more bytes, we can change the third line to add a bit more customisation:

```
"\__/"aiv
"&-1v!?:<&a" ()
__\"\~"/
?!;o>l
```

This produces one of those lamps which shoot light upwards, for lack of a better way of putting it:

```
\__/
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 46 bytes

```
cat("RRRR",rep(" ()",scan()),"/__\\",sep="\n")
```

In this version, **input** and **output** are almost mixed together :

**{in/out}PUT :**

```
> cat("RRRR",rep(" ()",scan()),"/__\\",sep="\n")
1: 4
2: 
Read 1 item
RRRR
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

*EDIT 1* : **-2** bytes thanks to @manatwork comment.
*EDIT 2* : **-6** bytes. Full credit goes to @manatwork again

Comment: Changes nothing but the look: `" /_\\"` should be `"/__\\"`. BTW, is that `\r` necessary?

Comment: @manatwork It did change the shape of the lamp's foot, making it more stable + your remark about `\r` saved me two bytes ! Should have re-read my code ! Thanks !

Comment: Hmm… Weird tool. Can't make it to work non-interactively. Anyway, `cat("RRRR",rep(" ()",scan()),"/__\\",sep="\n")` seems to work.

Comment: @manatwork : well... I've never thought that this could work ! It's indeed a nice solution. R is full of surprises !

Comment: Bonjour Frédéric, if you're still active on PPCG [you can save 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCNEpyi1QENJQUNTSac4OTFPQ1NTR0k/Pj4mBshPLbBVislT0vxvaPAfAA)

Answer (score 3):

### [Straw](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 26 bytes (non-competing)

```
<#~('--'
)>( ()
)-*>(/__\)>
```

Use `'--'` as lamp shade, <s>take input in unary</s> now in decimal

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @BetaDecay *therefore noncompeting

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
"/__\
"" ()
"ri*1$
```

Sample run for input 5:

```
/__\
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%2F__%5C%0A%22%22%20()%0A%22ri*1%24&input=5)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 34 bytes

```
i=>`|==|
${` ()
`.repeat(i)}/__\\`
```

The newlines are significant

Example with input of 5:

```
|==|
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 2):

## sed, 28 bytes

```
s#.# ()\n#g
s#^\|$#/__\\\n#g
```

Takes input in unary. The shade is the obvious selection (same as the base).

#### Test run

```
$ echo -n 111 | sed -f lamp.sed
/__\
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ (и„/_.ø)˜∞
```

-2 bytes (17 → 15) thanks to *@EriktheOutgolfer*.
-2 byte (13 → 11) after being inspired by [*@dzaima*'s Canvas answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169643/52210).

Cap is the same as the base (`/__\`).

**Explanation:**

```python
„ (            # Literal string " ("
   и           # Repeat " (" the input amount of times
               #  i.e. " (" and 3 → [' (',' (',' (']
    „/_        # Literal string "/_"
       .ø      # Surround the list of " (" with "/_" on both ends
               #  i.e. [' (',' (',' ('] → ['/_',[' (',' (',' (',' ('],'/_']
         ˜     # Flatten this list
               #  i.e. ['/_',[' (',' (',' ('],'/_'] → ['/_',' (',' (',' (','/_']
          ∞    # Mirror each item
               #  i.e. ['/_',' (',' (',' (','/_'] → ['/__\',' () ',' () ',' () ','/__\']
               # And output the list new-line delimited (implicitly due to the mirror)
```

---

**Old 13 bytes answer:**

```python
„/_D„ (Iиs)˜∞
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcM8/XgXIKmg4XlhR7Hm6TmPOub9/28CAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), 114 bytes

```
11+""*+"*";";";;1.1##(A|11+""""**+;)"""*"**;""*""*+*";1+;"\"1+/<1+#(A)11+"*(|1+"1+")1+*+;1()"*"1+*++";;1()*"1+*+;
```

You all! Stop complaining about the length, this is the best I could do! Go blame Parcly Taxel for designing such a bowly language!

Shade is `$$$$`.

Comment: Throwing shade I see

Comment: @Razetime What do you mean

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 36 bytes

```
print"-"*4+"\n ()"*input()+"\n/__\\"
```

For input 4:

```
----
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Note that for Python that any lamp shade using pipes is a byte less.

-1 bytes thanks to @Alex!

Comment: I think if you change the lampshade to a single character and multiply it by 4 you can save one byte: `print"-"*4+"\n ()"*input()+"\n/__\\"`

Answer (score 1):

## jq: 30 characters

(29 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```
8888,(range(.)|" ()"),"/__\\"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -r '8888,(range(.)|" ()"),"/__\\"' <<< 3
8888
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=8888,%28range%28.%29|%22%20%28%29%22%29,%22/__%5C%22&j=3) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

## Gema: 30 characters

```
*=gema\n@repeat{*;\ ()\n}/__\\
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '*=gema\n@repeat{*;\ ()\n}/__\\' <<< 3
gema
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 54 bytes

Call `f()` with the desired height of the lamp.

```
f(n){for(puts("||||");n--;puts(" ()"));puts("/__\\");}
```

[Try it on ideone.](http://ideone.com/2IYsrm)

Example output for 5:

```
||||
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 15 bytes

```
" ()"~mQAD"/__\
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk:3434/?code=%22+%28%29%22%7EmQAD%22%2F__%5C&input=11)

```
     ~m         - 1000
" ()"           -  " ()"
       QAD      - duplicate(^) input times
          "/__\ - "/__\"
```

Outputs:

```
1000
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 5.1, <del>28</del> 26 Bytes

<sub>Thanks Mazzy for 2 bytes</sub>

```
8008;," ()"*"$args";"/__\"
```

Since the shade can be any 4 characters, using a number saves a pair of quotes. The hardest part was finding a nice looking shade.

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\ItsMe\Desktop> .\scratch.ps1 4
8008
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Comment: nice lamp shade )

Comment: try this `8008;," ()"*"$args";"/__\"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 36 bytes

```
{"|MM|\n${" ()\n".repeat(it)}/__\\"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BC4JAEEbv/Yph6TBzyIhukkrHIE9dF2ShTZbWUdYpKPW3b1r0nd/33r0V7zjeHgyNcYwm1H0KxxDM63CR4LjOCYYVzHsaD940XQp4YiHY5PAjIIuDGsty1LweFCBpVkmwnTWCTmjaVpXWaop/Se/eFjII1lzPji1SkUg7K5GgSGH3jXWzWDzjEsTlQLSa4v4D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
(×_¶/ｅ⟳║
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTI4JUQ3XyVCNi8ldUZGNDUldTI3RjMldTI1NTE_,i=NQ__,v=5,run)

Explanation:

```
(×        repeat "(" input times
  _¶/e    encase it on both sides in "_\n/"
          the 1st line is surrounded in "_" and the second ends and starts with "/"
      ⟳   rotate the string clockwise without changing characters
       ║  palindromize horizontally with 0 overlap
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 169 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][S S S T S T T   T   S S N
_Push_92_\][S S S T S T T   T   T   T   N
_Push_95__][S N
S _Duplicate_95__][S S S T  S T T   T   T   N
_Push_47_/][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][T  T   T   _Retrieve_at_address_0][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    T   S _Store_at_address_0][N
T   T   S N
_If_neg_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10_newline][S S S T   S T S S T   N
_Push_41_)][S S S T S T S S S N
_Push_40_(][S S S T S S S S S N
_Push_32_space][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10_newline][S S S T   S S S S T   N
_Push_33_!][S N
S _Duplicate_33_!][S N
S _Duplicate_33_!][S N
S _Duplicate_33_!][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_LOOP_2][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP_2]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RY1LCoAwDETX806RQ3ghkULdCQoeP7ZJWyEwk/kkbz2fcl/7UdzNDCE1lKkjk0rEMjZID2UadScCpNjPjPbClptsaFFoDViSfit/xhBPkgr37QM) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

Pushes all characters in reversed order to the stack, and then prints them in a loop.

```
Integer i = STDIN as input
Push "\__/" to the stack
Start LOOP:
  i = i - 1
  if(i is negative):
    Go to function PRINT
  Push "\n)( " to the stack
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT:
  Push "\n!!!!" to the stack
  Start LOOP_2:
    Print top as character to STDOUT
    Go to next iteration of LOOP_2
```

NOTE: `i` in the pseudo-code above is stored back in the heap in every iteration of `LOOP`, because we don't want to leave it on the stack to be printed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 31 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input as a numeric from range `[A1]` and outputs to the calling cell.

This lamp is musical - and will help to liven and lighten up your day.

```
="/\
"&REPT(" ()
",A1)&"/__\"
```

#### Output

[image: I love lamp]

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 bytes

```
Æ` ()`Ãi¥² p"/__\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3BbgoKGZsLh5sxDSw9tUihQ0o@Pj/n/35SLSzcIAA)

Output for `5` is:

```
====
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `¥`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <s>65</s> 61 bytes

```
@95W2M!;2A!!;;2W2M;[25W;84W;85W!;1M;1A]25W;95W2M!;2W1M!!;;3A;
```

I'm sure it can be golfed by a few more bytes when displaying characters.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%4095W2M!%3B2A!!%3B%3B2W2M%3B%5B25W%3B84W%3B85W!%3B1M%3B1A%5D25W%3B95W2M!%3B2W1M!!%3B%3B3A%3B&input=9)

Comment: Why? :( (15 chars)

Comment: gimme 1+ answer

Comment: Ok workin' on it

Comment: ...done. Almost two times as long as your program...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 15 bytes

```
×d?(‛ ()‛/_WvøṀ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C3%97d%3F%28%E2%80%9B%20%28%29%E2%80%9B%2F_Wv%C3%B8%E1%B9%80&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Example output:

```
****
 () 
 () 
 () 
 () 
/__\
```

I kinda golfed the shade.

```
×d              # two asterisks
  ?(   )        # Input times...
    ‛ (         # Push the two-char ` (`
        ‛/_     # Push the two-char `/_`
           W    # Push the entire stack
            vøṀ # Ascii-art mirror each item.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 118 characters

Strings consist of `char` values.
The available `char` values beyond the bare minimum (i. e. necessary to write Pascal language elements) are implementation-defined.
Provided that all `char` values present are available in your implementation, you can write:

```pascal
program p(input,output);var l:integer;begin
read(l);writeLn('‥〜');for l:=1 to l do
writeLn(' ()');write('/__\')end.
```

Input:

```
4
```

Output (pun intended):

```markdown
‥〜
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

<sup>This lamp grants you a wish if you rub it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## SWI-Prolog, <s>73</s> 60 bytes

```
a(X):-write(golf),writef("%r",["\n ()",X]),write("\n/__\\").
```

`a(5).` outputs

```
golf
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 36 bytes

```matlab
n->print("|~~|\n"*" ()\n"^n*"/__\\")
```

This creates an unnamed function that takes an integer as input and prints to stdout.

Example:

```matlab
julia> f(4)
|~~|
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java <s>7</s> 11, <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 37 bytes

```java
n->"i!!i\n"+" ()\n".repeat(n)+"/__\\"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nVFBTsMwELz3FdNcsNUkpSBOFdxBohzg1lSVm2xJSmJH9qaoQn17cFpLFRJcuFhez8yOd3an9irZFR99Xivn8Kwq/TUCKs1ktyonLIYSeGVb6XfkwiPQcu4fjyN/OFZc5VhA4x69Th6iajyuMh1NLLWkWEQQ0pexlpNoul5nWdTPB2HbbWovDPq9qQo03lycjZYrKBmcD46pSU3HaeshrrXQaS5u5OkTv@J/I4Py9t/KO3kZfDrF2@MLCkNOXzFc17bGMp58npjNcCCO4QxKsoQQxXm02PeTaIhLU4ANqOlqxRQSTgP3RNoaCy4JTjWEzYEpyU2n@RJ72MqP/h6zgwdUM5BDipa4sxqaPoNIDNe8VHZ55q3kYF37lYsou45i3yUMe@y/AQ) (NOTE: Java 11 isn't supported on TIO yet, so `String.repeat(int)` has been emulated with `repeat(String,int)` for the same byte-count.)

Uses `i!!i` as cap. [`¡!!¡` looks better](https://tio.run/##nVFBbsIwELzziiGX2iKE0qon1N5bqfTQ3ghCJlma0MSO7A0VqngMX@Fj1AFLqFJ76cXyenZmvLNrtVHDdf5xzCrlHJ5Vqb96QKmZ7EplhGlXAq9sS/2OTHgEWk78467nD8eKywxTaNzjqIcP0WHf7x/2qY4GlhpSLCII6ctYy0E0WizSNDpOOmrTLitPDQobU@aovb04W83mUDJ4bx1TnZiWk8ZDXGmhk0zcyNM3fsX/Rjrm7b@Zd/Iy@miEt8cX5IacvmK4tmmMZTz5RDEeY0scwxkUZAkhivNosdeTqIkLk4MNqG4rxRQyTkLvqWllLLggOFUTllumYWZazZfgw15@6HvMdh5QddccUrTErdXQ9BlIortmhbKzc99cdtaVX7qI0uso9iph2N3xGw), but is two bytes more.

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                    // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  "i!!i\n"             //  Return the cap + new-line
  " ()\n".repeat(n)    //   appended with " ()" and a new-line `n` amount of times
  "/__\\"              //   append with "/__\"
```

Answer (score 0):

## PyMin, 24 bytes / 17 characters

```
»ƒ+ѿ+" ø\n"*¬+ɓ+ѿ
```

Output for 5:

```
Fizz
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
Buzz
```

Shorter version with `v0.5`:

#### 21 bytes / 13 characters

```
»ƒƜ+" ø¶"¯+ɓƜ
```

Comment: The base of the lamp must be /__\.

Answer (score 0):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 28 bytes

```
{n|"[~~]
"+" ()
"*n+"/--\\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + coreutils, 37 bytes

```sh
yes ' ()'|sed '1i####
'$1'{a/__\\
q}'
```

The newlines are necessary and counted in the bytes total. GNU sed is required.

**Run:**

```sh
./squiggly_lamp.sh 2
```

**Output:**

```sh
####
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 42 bytes

```
i=gets.to_i
puts "|--|\n#{" ()\n"*i}/__\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 26 bytes

```
"-"4*P?I(" ()"P?!i)"/__\"P
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=Ii0iNCpQP0koIiAoKSJQPyFpKSIvX19cIlA&input=Mw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 38 bytes

```
I"|MM|"Wr
~W" ()"oN<s!:-1~
@W"/__\"oN<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/99TqcbXt0YpvIirLlxJQUNTKd/PpljRStewjsshXEk/Pj4GJPL/vzEA)

### Samples

```
1
|MM|
 ()
/__\

2
|MM|
 ()
 ()
/__\

3
|MM|
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link to an online testing environment so one can easily run your submission?

Comment: @JonathanFrech TIO link now available

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

```perl
$_=$<.'
 ()'x$_.'
/--\
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbFRk@dS0FDU71CJR7I0tfVjeFS///fkMuIy5jLhMv0X35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA)

Uses `1000` as the cap.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 50 bytes

```
"\__/"&v
0-1_v#:<g00" ()"*25p0
*25$<>:#,_@#::::"_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XykmPl5fSa2My0DXML5M2com3cBASUFDU0nLyLTAgAtIqtjYWSnrxDsoWwGBUrzS//9GAA)

Example with Input 3

```
____
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 38 bytes

```php
/--\<?while($argn--)echo"
 ()"?>

/__\
```

Save to file; run as pipe with `-nF` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5e0381f8ab130c7da04b87d5f6577a1eb26e8c3).

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
8Ｅ⊕Ｎ(←_/‖Ｍ
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@ASCII-only*.
-1 byte thanks to *@Neil* by using a `Map`.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJQknTmgvC9k0s0PDMSy5KzU3NK0lNAbILSkv8SnOTUos0NDV1FJQ0lDThiq18UtNKgGLx@iADglLTclKTS3wzi4rygYqt//83@a9blgMA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9jaGFyY29hbP//OO@8peKKle@8rijihpBfL@KAlu@8rf//NA).

Uses `8()8` as cap, but the `8` can be any character from Charcoal's code-page that isn't used as a command/operator.

**Explanation:**

Print `8`:

```
Print("8");
8
```

Print `(` the `input+1` amount of times downwards:

```
Print(Map(Incremented(InputNumber()), "("));
Ｅ⊕Ｎ(
```

Then after that print `_/` in a left direction:

```
Print(:Left, "_/");
←_/
```

And finally mirror everything vertically:

```
ReflectMirror();
‖Ｍ
```

Comment: [12?](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREOp2kJJ05rLN78sVcPKJb88zyc1rQQoAJEFi@gohGTmphZrKGko6Sh45hWUlviV5ialFmloaiIUgrTpKCjF64NMC0pNy0lNLvHNLCrKByqz/v/f5L9uWQ4A)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks! Forgot about `Print(... Time(...));`, and smart way of using `Move(:DownLeft);` so regular Prints instead of MultiPrints can be used and the space at `" ("` can be saved at the same time.

Comment: You can save a byte here using `Map` too, although you'll need to rewrite the way you print the `{8` so that you don't have to explicitly move to the next line.

Comment: @Neil I've found a few 12-byte alternatives with `Map`, but not 11 yet. [Alternative 1](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREOp2iImT0nTmgvC9U0s0PDMKygt8SvNTUot0tDUUVBS0FDShCtQ0o8HqQ5KTctJTS7xzSwqygeqsv7/3@S/blkOAA); [Alternative 2](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREOp2iImT0FJ05oLwvdNLNDwzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFQ0lDShMtb@aSmlQDF4vVBeoJS03JSk0t8M4uK8oFqrf//N/mvW5YDAA).

Comment: Alternative 2 is closer, but you can print those two characters in 3 bytes and still end up with the cursor in the correct place.

Comment: @Neil Still not sure how to do `{8` in 3 bytes while moving the cursor at the same time, but I've been able to golf 2 bytes instead of 1 by using `8(` instead of `{8` as lamp shade. Still curious how to do the `{8` in 3 bytes through. :)

Comment: `Print("{"); Print(:Down, "8");`

Comment: @Neil Ah, of course! So simple now that I see it..

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 164 bytes

```
({}<((((((((((()()){}()){})()){}()){}())){}()))[[]]()){({}<>)<>}<>>()){({}[()]<(((((((()()){}()){}){}){}())[()])[(()()()()){}])((()()()()()){})>)}(((({}{}{}{}{}))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O61kYDATQ1NDWra8EEEhNIQMno6NhYkBBIm52mjR2QtIPyozU0Y22wmQNGQCZIAZAAyUHlYzU14FyIWjvNWpD26loYBNqp@f@/6X9dRwA)

Output for `5`:

```
{{{{
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
 ()
/__\
```