# Snakes all around

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

### Challenge

The challenge is simple: **print a snake**.
You will get the length of the snake as input.
A snake of length 2 looks like this:

```
==(:)-
```

A snake of length 7 looks like this:

```
=======(:)-
```

In other words, *the length of a snake is how many equal signs are before the head*.

### Usage

Let's say I made a C++ implementation and compiled it to `./getsnake`.
I could run it like so:

```
$ ./getsnake 10
==========(:)-
```

### Clarifications

- [Standard loopholes are disallowed.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1070#1070)
- You can get input and output in any acceptable way.
- You can assume all inputs given are positive integers.
- You may write a function instead of a regular program.

Comment: It's kinda useless to leave a challenge in the Sandbox for only half an hour. You did get some feedback, but it's usually best to leave it in the Sandbox for 24-72 hours. (Also, you should either flesh out the "Origins" part or remove it.)

Comment: Is a function enough or do you want a full program?

Comment: @betseg function is enough

Comment: What if the input is 0?

Comment: @Fatalize Or `NaN`, `Infinity`, any negative number, or a blank string?

Comment: @Fatalize the program will only ever get positive integers

Comment: @Peanut the program will only ever get positive integers

Comment: I'm afraid all [My Squiggly Lamp](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53483/my-squiggly-lamp) answers are effortlessly portable to this.

Comment: Is zero positive?

Comment: @Peanut no, it isn't

Comment: Negative integers should cause the snake to swallow itself.

Comment: Are functions that return a string (rather than printing it) valid?

Comment: Is hardcoding the input (i.e. you have to replace "n" with the number in the program to run it) allowed, rather than taking input through stdin or equivalent?

Comment: @T.Lukin it isn't

Answer (score 19):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 33 bytes

Not gonna win, but still cool. Might be able to get golfed more.

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=NjF9Py4kKUAkajsoMzwuLzsufWwvLjQwMDs1XGo7Lidc&input=NQ)

Golfed:

```
61}?.$)@$j;(3<./;.}l/.400;5\j;.'\
```

Formatted:

```
    6 1 } ?
   . $ ) @ $
  j ; ( 3 < .
 / ; . } l / .
  4 0 0 ; 5 \
   j ; . ' \
    . . . .
```

Colored (Made using [Timwi's Hexagony Colorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer))

[image: u found da secret snek! =======(:)-]

Explanation:

Loop, print out "=" until the counter reaches 0.

```
    6 1 } ?
   . $ . . $
  . . ( . . .
 / . . } . . .
  . . . ; . .
   . . . ' .
    . . . .
```

Print "("

```
    . . . .
   . . . . .
  . . . . . .
 / ; . . . . .
  4 . . . . .
   j . . . .
    . . . .
```

Print ":"

```
    . . . .
   . . . . .
  . ; ( 3 < .
 . . . } l / .
  . . . . . .
   . . . . .
    . . . .
```

Print ")"

```
    . . . .
   . . . . .
  j . . . . .
 . . . . . . .
  . . . ; 5 \
   . . . . \
    . . . .
```

The above values were generated using a simple python script. However, I kind of ran out of room for the "-". So, I had to resort to more advanced tricks.

When the program prints out ")", the value of the cell isn't 41, it's 1065. Hexagony just mods the value when printing. As it turns out, (1065*1000+4)%256=44, just one away from 45, the ascii value for "-". Then, I just increment, print, and insert a @ somewhere after printing.

```
    . . . .
   . $ ) @ $
  j . . 3 . .
 / . . } . . .
  4 0 0 . 5 \
   . ; . . \
    . . . .
```

Comment: How can it be called a programming language when .j4/; is ... Print "("??? Which part of .j4/; is the print and which part is the string to print?

Comment: @Fogmeister [Part 1/2] In Hexagony, any alphabetical character sets the value of the current memory cell to the ascii value of that character. "j" has an ascii value of 106, so that is what the memory is set to. Also, and numerical characters multiply the value of the current cell by 10, then add themselves to it (this allows for easy construction of numbers, like the 61 at the beginning.

Comment: [Part 2/2] So, j4 sets the memory cell to 1064. When the IP reaches the "/", it gets reflected into ";", which prints out the ascii character corresponding to the current memory cell % 256. 1064%256=40, the ascii value for "(". I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks. Yeah it does. I guess this is more of a language to use as a way of testing your brain. Rather than a way to write programmes then? Interesting.

Comment: @Fogmeister there are *many* esoteric programming languages that are more brain twisting exercises than useful for doing real work, although they CAN do real work if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 12):

## Cinnamon Gum, 7 bytes

```
0000000: 7043 dc95 6d4f ce                        pC..mO.
```

[Try it online.](http://cinnamon-gum.tryitonline.net/#code=MDAwMDAwMDogNzA0MyBkYzk1IDZkNGYgY2UgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBwQy4ubU8u&input=MTA)

Would have been 6 bytes with the old `p` syntax :/

## Explanation

Decompresses to `p~=~(:)-`, the `p` stage then simply reads input and repeats the `=` n times.

Comment: Can you link to language spec for this?

Comment: @RobertFraser I don't have a formal specification or any documentation currently, but you can check out the source at the GitHub repo: https://github.com/quartata/cinnamon-gum

Answer (score 12):

### [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 31 bytes

```
,{-?>}-):(=?
#}<<.{?_<.<.<.<.<.
```

Input in the form of a [byte value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values), so e.g. input `!` gives a snake of length 33.

[Try it online!](http://brian-chuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LHstPz59LSk6KD0_CiN9PDwuez9fPC48LjwuPC48Lg&input=IQ)

It's been a while...

#### Explanation

A quick Brian & Chuck primer:

- The first line of the program is Brian, the second is Chuck.
- Brian and Chuck are two Brainfuck-like instances. The main catch is that Chuck's program is Brian's tape and vice versa. The tape heads/instruction pointers start on the first cell of each tape and execution starts on Brian.
- As for the commands, there are a few differences. Only Brian can use `,` (input) and only Chuck can use `.` (output). In addition to `<` and `>` there are `{` and `}` which move the tape head up to the next zero cell (or in the case of `{` to the left end of the tape if there is no zero cell on the way). Instead of `[...]`, the only control flow is `?` which switches control to the other instance if the current cell is non-zero. The first executed instruction on the other cell is the one after the condition. And finally, `_` is just an alias for null-bytes, for convenience.

Now the code. Brian starts with this:

```
,{-?
```

This reads the input into Chuck's first cell, then moves the tape head to the left with `{` (does nothing right now) and decrements the input with `-` before switching control for Chuck if the value is still non-zero. This begins the main loop. Chuck then runs this bit:

```
}<<.{?
```

This moves the tape head on Brian to the very end, moves two cells left onto the `=` and prints it before the tape head all the way to the left and switching control back to Brian. This is how loops generally work in B&C.

Once the input has been reduced to zero, the `?` on Brian's tape will do nothing. Then Brian executes this part:

```
>}-):(=?
```

The `):(=` are no-ops, so the actual code is just `>}-?`. We move off the zero cell with `>`, move up to `_` with `}`, decrement it to make it non-zero and switch to Chuck with `?`. Then the last bit on Chuck is run:

```
<.<.<.<.<.
```

This simply prints the five characters in front of Chuck, i.e. `=(:)-`. Note that we need to print another `=` since the main loop is only executed `N-1` times for input `N`.

Comment: Congrats on 100k

Answer (score 10):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 8 bytes

```
Àé=A(:)-
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w4DDqT1BKDopLQ&input=&args=NQ)

V uses the "Latin1" encoding.

Explanation:

```
À        "Arg1 times:
 é=      "Insert an '='
   A(:)- "Append the head
```

Comment: [I count 10 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%C3%80%C3%A9%3DA%28%3A%29-)

Comment: @zwei see my edit.

Comment: Got it! That's better.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
.+
$*=(:)-
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCo9KDopLQ&input=MTA)

This is a simple regex substitution.

It matches `.+` which matches the whole input, and then substitutes it with `$*=(;)-`.

The `$*` is a feature unique in Retina: it is the character-repetition special operator.

For example, `5$*x` would become `xxxxx`.

In the case that the previous argument is absent, the whole match is used as the default argument.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 21 bytes

```python
lambda n:"="*n+"(:)-"
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/flvOaZ)

Comment: You can cut 3 bytes by doing: `"="*input()+"(:)-"`

Comment: @gowrath Then it won't be printing anything

Comment: It'll output it if you're in the interpreter no? Op said you can get output in any way.

Comment: @gowrath You can't assume that we're in REPL

Comment: Is that a general rule for code golfing? New here :)

Comment: @gowrath Usually.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 52 bytes

```java
n->new String(new char[n]).replace("\0","=")+"(:)-";
```

[Test suite.](http://goo.gl/Ur0Kys) (Compile > Execute)

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/6211883).

#### teh traditional way, <s>61</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

**7 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.**

**1 byte thanks to Dom Hastings.**

```java
n->{String s="";for(;n-->0;)s+="=";return s+"(:)-";};
```

Comment: +1 Oh, and for the traditional one: `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` can be golfed to `for(;n>0;n--)`, since you don't need the input for anything else than the for-loop anyway.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, edited

Comment: Testing via the link you provided it looks like you can change the for loop to: `for(;n-->0;)` to save another byte!

Comment: @DomHastings edited with thanks

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 25 bytes

```
f n=('='<$[1..n])++"(:)-"
```

`'='<$[1..n]` is equivalent to `replicate n '='`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”=x;“(:)-
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdPXg74oCcKDopLQ&input=&args=MTA)

```
”=x;“(:)-
”=          '='
  x         repeat (argument) that many times
   ;        append
    “(:)-   "(:)-"
```

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
'=×"ÿ(:)-
```

**Explanation**

```
'=         # push equal-sign
  ×        # repeat input nr of times
   "ÿ(:)-  # interpolate snake body with head as a string
           # implicitly display
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Jz3DlyLDvyg6KS0&input=NQ)

1 byte saved thanks to Adnan.

Comment: [`'=×"ÿ(:)-`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Jz3DlyLDvyg6KS0&input=NQ) for 9 bytes :). This uses string interpolation.

Comment: @Adnan: Aaah, so that's what `ÿ` does :)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 38

```
f(n){for(;n--;printf(n?"=":"=(:)-"));}
```

[Try it on ideone.](http://ideone.com/I7HpkV)

Comment: Not shorter, but cooler: `f(n){~-printf(n?"=":"=(:)-")||f(~-n);}`.

Comment: `f(n){for(;n;printf(n--?"=":"(:)-"));}` for -1.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ - That doesn't output the head.

Comment: @owacoder Well, C is not my primary language...

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ And that's why you shouldn't post untested golfing suggestions (especially if it would have taken you 5 seconds to test your suggestion with the link provided in the answer).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 23 bytes

```
n=>"=".repeat(n)+"(:)-"
```

Comment: I was just about to post exactly that code! Beat me to it! Have an upvote

Comment: Today I learned about [arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/). Thank you. Didn't know that was a thing

Comment: How do you call that instance of the function? I just tried `n(3)` and received a `Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined` error...

Comment: @WallyWest - try `x=n=>"=".repeat(n)+"(:)-"; x(7);`

Comment: @eithedog Then shouldn't the answer have the initial `x=` and changed to 25 chars?

Comment: @WallyWest no, because the requirement is `You may write a function instead of a regular program`. `x=` is the assignment of the anonymous function

Answer (score 4):

### C#,  28 bytes

```
n=>new string('=',n)+"(:)-";
```

Comment: im always interested by the lambda snippets. how can you even run this?

Comment: @downrep_nation it takes in an int and automatically returns the string because it is only one statement

Comment: The answer should be a full program or a function, not just a snippet. So this answer seems incomplete.

Comment: @raznagul This is an anonymous function therefore it is complete

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Maybe try online link would help to understand it. (http://csharppad.com/)

Comment: Under Clarifications OP wrote "You may write a function instead of a regular program," so I think this is valid on that count. However, it does not actually print anything when invoked, and I'm not sure that's kosher since the requirements say "print a snake." (If it was `n=>Console.Write(new string...);` I believe that would be valid.)

Comment: @Jordan •You can get input and output in **any acceptable way.**. I take that to mean returning the string is valid output

Comment: @raznagul It is essentially a `Func<int, string>` just anonymous

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://repl.it/repls/RewardingAncientPaddlefish), 24 bytes.

```
print"="*input()+"(:)-"
```

`input()` gets input from user

`*`, when used on strings and an integer, creates a new string, which is made of joined copies of the original. For example: `"hello "*3` outputs `hello hello hello`.

By multiplying `=` and `input()`, you get a string of `=` the length that the user specifies.

Using `+` joins two strings, in this case, our body `"=…="` with our head, `"(:)-"` to make the snake.

`print` outputs the result.

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```python
~"="*"(:)-"
```

Multiplies "=" by input, and adds head.

*-1 thanks to Leaky Nun*

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
"="~Table~#<>"(:)-"&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number *n* as input, and returns a snake of length *n* as output. `"="~Table~#` generates a list `{"=", "=", ..., "="}` of length *n*, and `<>"(:)-"` concatenates the list's elements and appends `"(:)-"` to the resulting string.

Comment: golfable by one more byte: `"="~Table~#<>"(:)-"&`

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 68 bytes

```
@set h=(:)-
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call set h==%%h%%
@echo %h%
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>32</s> 27 bytes

This solution is pretty straightforward, `rep` function repeats the first element (`"="`) `scan()` times, which is in fact the user's input.

```
a=scan();cat(rep("=",a),"(:)-")
```

*EDIT*:

```
cat(rep("=",scan()),"(:)-")
```

Slighly shorter answer, using `scan()` directly.

Alternatively,

```
cat(rep("=",scan()),"(:)-",sep="")
```

for a non-chopped snake (**34 bytes**)

Comment: I would say the `sep=""` is needed here, otherwise your snake looks like the one that traversed the railway: `= = = (:)-`.

Comment: The snake produced here is indeed a bit minced, but OP's consigns only state that the length of the snake is the number of equal signs before the head. I will add the  `sep` as a side note nonetheless ;)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <del>46</del> <del>45</del> <del>43</del> bytes

*saved 2 bytes thanks to owacoder!*
*saved 3 bytes thanks to rici!*

```c
f(n){while(4-printf("=\0(:)-"+2*!n--));}
```

[Try it on Ideone!](https://ideone.com/DXVJJh)

Comment: The mysterious [`-->` operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/6211883) strikes again.

Comment: @LeakyNun 46 bytes version was without the goes to operator, than I remembered the goes to operator ;)

Comment: You can remove the `>0` and save two bytes.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `f(n){while(4-printf("=\0(:)-"+2*!n--));}`

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
qi'=*"(:)-"
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi%7B'%3D%7D*%22(%3A)-%22&input=5)

*-2 bytes thanks to quartata*

Comment: You can do `'=*` instead of `{'=}*`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JAISBaL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL), 9 bytes

```
t=*Qb(:)-
```

Verbose:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
push1 =        \# push = onto the stack #\
mul            \# multiply the top two values of the stack #\
popout         \# pop the top value of a stack and print it #\
print4 (:)-    \# print (:)- #\
```

Tested with [JAISBaL-0.0.7](https://dl.bintray.com/meguy26/Main/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/JAISBaL/0.0.7/)
(The compiled .jar was just pushed, but the source has been up on git for a while)

Comment: Use a `#` before the language name to make it look like everybody else's.

Comment: @MichaelKlein okay

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>16 15</s>  12 bytes

```perl6
{"{'='x$_}(:)-"}
{'='x$_~'(:)-'}
'='x*~'(:)-'
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
'=' x * # ｢=｣ string repeated by the only parameter ｢*｣
~        # concatenated with
'(:)-'   # the head
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# store it in the lexical namespace
my &snake = '='x*~'(:)-';

put snake 10;

# put ^5 .map: &snake;
put ^5 .map: '='x*~'(:)-';
```

```
==========(:)-
(:)- =(:)- ==(:)- ===(:)- ====(:)- =====(:)-
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 19 bytes

```
'='*$args[0]+'(:)-'
```

Full program. Takes input `$args[0]`, uses string multiplication to construct the body, then string concatenation to tack on the head.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\snakes-all-around.ps1 7
=======(:)-

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\snakes-all-around.ps1 77
=============================================================================(:)-
```

Comment: Kudos to you, I got as far as 26:
`"$("="*[int]$args[0])(:)-"`

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 15 bytes (noncompeting)

```
n->'='*n+'(:)-'
```

A straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 11 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: aaaa5e a0f7b4 ed4cee 5d3b                         ..^....L.];
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bWluCmFkZCA2MQpmd2QgMQpnZXQKam1wLHN1YiAxLHJ3ZCAxLHB1dCxmd2QgMSxqbnoKYWRkIDQwLHB1dApyd2QgMSxzdWIgMyxwdXQKZndkIDEsYWRkIDEscHV0CmFkZCA0LHB1dA&input=MTA&debug=on)

Assembler:

```lisp
set numin
add 61
fwd 1
get
jmp,sub 1,rwd 1,put,fwd 1,jnz
add 40,put
rwd 1,sub 3,put
fwd 1,add 1,put
add 4,put
```

Answer (score 1):

### K, 17 Bytes

```
{,[x#"=";"(:)-"]}
```

Example;

```
f:{,[x#"=";"(:)-"]}
-1(f'!10);          /print out the result of calling f where x is 0 1 2 3 4 5....
(:)-
=(:)-
==(:)-
===(:)-
====(:)-
=====(:)-
======(:)-
=======(:)-
========(:)-
=========(:)-
```

Explanation;

```
{}                 /function x is implicit and is an int
x#"="              /take (#) x of "=" --> so 3#"=" gives "==="
,[x#"=";"(:)-"]    /comma is a join that takes 2 args --> ,[x;y] gives the concatination of x and y --> "a","abc" is the same as ,["a";"abc"] and gives "aabc"
```

Comment: What is `-1(`...`);`?

Comment: Save a byte: `{(x#"="),"(:)-"}`

Comment: Thanks Adam.
-1 Prints to the console.
-1"Hello"; will print Hello

Comment: But isn't printing implicit?

Comment: Yes but it includes the double quotes...
"====(:)-" rather than; =====(:)-

Comment: save 2 bytes with `{|"-):(",x#"="}`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7pGSVfTSkNJp0JZyVap1tDg/38A "K (oK) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 16 + 1 (`-p` flag) = 17 bytes

```
$_="="x$_."(:)-"
```

Needs `-p` flag, so run with :

```
perl -pe '$_="="x$_."(:)-"'
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 12 bytes

```
"=(:)-"nD$O.
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%22%3D%28%3A%29-%22nD%24O%2E&input=7)

#### Explanation

```
"=(:)-"         Push this to the stack in reverse order - ["-",")",":","(","="]
       n        Take number from input
        D       Pop k and duplicate top of stack (the "=") k times
         $O.    Output whole stack as characters and stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-98, 24 bytes

Takes numerical input from the user, then prints the snake.

```
'=&:00pk:00gk,"-):("4k,@
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab / Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(n)[~(1:n)+61 '(:)-']
```

This is an anonymous function.

[**Try it on Ideone**](http://ideone.com/sVU0ez).

#### Explanation

Assume `n= 5`.

`1:n` produces the row vector `[1 2 3 4 5]`.

`~(1:n)` negates each entry, so it gives `[0 0 0 0 0]`.

`...+61` adds `61` to each entry, so it gives `[61 61 61 61 61]`. `61` is the ASCII value of character `=`.

`[... '(:)-']` concatenates that with the string `'(:)-'`. This automatically converts `[61 61 61 61 61]` into the string `'====='` before the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 13 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'(:)-',⍨⍴∘'='
```

`'(:)-',⍨` the snake head appended to
`⍴∘'='` *n* repetitions of a body segment

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%27%28%3A%29-%27%2C%u2368%u2374%u2218%27%3D%27%20%u22C4%20f%A82%207%2010&run)

A proper function. The equivalent program is `'(:)-',⍨⎕⍴'='`.

Comment: You forgot the byte count.

Comment: @m654 The snake nibbled it!

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 53 bytes

```
++++[->+++++<]>[->+++>++<<],>+<[->.<]>>.<---.>+.++++.
```

Explanation:

```
++++[->+++++<]    We build a 20 as 5*4
>[->+++>++<<]     We build a 60 and a 40 in two neighboring cells out of the 20, by multiplying the 20 with 3 and with 2
,>+<[->.<]        Read input, and print 61 ('=') as many times as the input idicates
>>.<---.>+.++++.  Print out the rest, "(:)-", noting how close each character is to either 60 or 40.
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 COM, 29 bytes

```
8A 0E 82 00 80 E9 30 B4
02 B2 3D CD 21 49 75 FB
BA 18 01 B4 09 CD 21 C3
28 3A 29 2D 24
```

aka

```
16DA:0100 8A0E8200      MOV     CL,[0082]
16DA:0104 80E930        SUB     CL,30
16DA:0107 B402          MOV     AH,02
16DA:0109 B23D          MOV     DL,3D
16DA:010B CD21          INT     21
16DA:010D 49            DEC     CX
16DA:010E 75FB          JNZ     010B
16DA:0110 BA1801        MOV     DX,0118
16DA:0113 B409          MOV     AH,09
16DA:0115 CD21          INT     21
16DA:0117 C3            RET
16DA:0118 283A          SUB     [BP+SI],BH // Snake Head
16DA:011A 292D          SUB     [DI],BP    // Snake Head
16DA:011C 2400          AND     AL,00      // Snake Head
```

Name it "snake.com"

Call it from cmd (tested with Win XP), parameters 1 to 9 supported:

```
snake 5
```

results in

```
=====(:)-
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 42 bytes

```
string w(int n)=>new string('=',n)+"(:)-";
```

[Try it here!](http://csharppad.com/gist/64e903e18e5ade4aea3a673343fc37ea)

Comment: Does this code print the string?

Comment: @Jordan: No, this is a function that returns the string.

Comment: The requirements say solutions should "print a snake." I'm not sure if just returning a string is kosher.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 28 Bytes

Takes input in the form of a command-line argument and outputs via its return value. Even if it uses a return statement, it is still a full program :).

```lua
return("="):rep(...).."(:)-"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [LiveScript](http://livescript.net), 15 bytes

```
->'='*it+'(:)-'
```

Answer (score 1):

## BASIC, 30 bytes

Let's keep it simple in BASIC.  QB64 and TRS-80 Extended Color BASIC both tie, since TRS-80 needs a line number but doesn't need the space after `INPUT`, and it won't let you use `INPUT` in immediate mode.  One liners are rare on a 32x16 screen.

### TRS-80: *(should also work on Microsoft GW-BASIC/BASICA)*

```
0INPUTL:?STRING$(L,"=");"(:)-"
```

[image]

### QB64:

```
INPUT L:?STRING$(L,"=");"(:)-"
```

Comment: GW-BASIC seems to require a space after INPUT.

Comment: My old Model 1 Level 1 could use abbreviations like "I." for "INPUT" but I don't think Level 1 BASIC had STRING$.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 1.7, 46 bytes

A recursive (and shorter) alternative to the [iterative](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87138/56948) and ['replace'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87142/56948) versions.

```
String f(int n){return n>0?"="+f(--n):"(:)-";}
```

[Run it here.](https://ideone.com/ik3iC0)

This function first builds the *n* tail elements recursively, then appends the head.

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
+[+<-[<]>->>++]<<++<,[->.<]<.>>---.<<+.++++.
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1srPC1bPF0-LT4-KytdPDwrKzwsWy0-LjxdPC4-Pi0tLS48PCsuKysrKy4&input=IQ) Takes input as a single byte value (e.g. space is 32). The program requires an interpreter with 8-bit cells and a tape not bounded on the left.

`+[+<-[<]>->>++]` (found by a bit of brute forcing) initialises the tape to

```
[253, 0, 0, 232, 0, 0, 40, 0, 59, 86, 0]
                                      ^
```

We then increment the 59 to 61 with `<<++` and read the input char with `<,`. `[->.<]` then outputs the required number of `=`, and `<.>>---.<<+.++++.` outputs the `(:)-` portion, making use of the aforementioned 61 as well as the 40 two cells away.

Answer (score 1):

## Fish (><>), 33 bytes:

An upside down F cause ><>. Takes integer as command line argument by running 
`./fish.py snake.fish -v [number]`.

```
\
"
-
)
:
(!;!?lo<
=
"
>{1-:?!^}:
```

Try it [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)! The best explanation is to watch it with animation on the website.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 93, 25 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#JsGxp)

```
1+:&`#v_"=",
"(:)-"<@,,,,
```

Not compatible with '98, because the `&` character [acts like `r`](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html#Stdio) when there is no input, instead of repeating the last token

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 59 bytes

As unnamed lambda:

```c++
#import<string>
[](int n){return std::string(n,61)+"(:)-";}
```

Usage:

```c++
#include<iostream>

#import<string>
auto f=
  [](int n){return std::string(n,61)+"(:)-";}
;

int main(){
  std::cout << f(2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << f(5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << f(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Turing machine code, 242 bytes

```
0 * * r 0
0 _ _ l A
A 0 9 l A
A 1 0 r 1
A 2 1 r 1
A 3 2 r 1
A 4 3 r 1
A 5 4 r 1
A 6 5 r 1
A 7 6 r 1
A 8 7 r 1
A 9 8 r 1
A _ _ r 3
1 _ = l 2
1 * * r 1
2 = = l 2
2 * * * A
3 = = r 4
3 * _ r 3
4 = = r 4
4 _ ( r 6
6 _ : r 7
7 _ ) r 8
8 _ - * halt
```

[Try it online.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?8ad77c69f425864596df578eb668d0c1)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 29 bytes

```
(format t"~v{=~}(:)-"(read)1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

Saved 4 bytes by putting the `"-):("` at the beginning. This let me get rid of the separate printing of the head, and also the `'` for pushing the `=`.

```
"-):(="&k:$$>:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X0lX00rDVkkt20pFxc5KWSfe4f9/QwMA)

#### Explanation

```
"-):(="                   Pushes '-):(=' to the stack - the head reversed
       &k:                Duplicates the = N+1 times (now there are N+2 '='s on the stack)
          $$              Discards 2 so that there are N '='s
            >:#,_         Prints all the top non-zero chars on the stack (the whole snake)
                 @        Exits
```

Answer (score 1):

**VBA Excel, 23 bytes**

using Immediate window and cell [A1] as input

`?string([A1],"=")"(:)-"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
\=*\:øb‹+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFw9KlxcOsO4YuKAuSsiLCIiLCIyXG43Il0=)

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFw9KlxcOsO4YuKAuSsiLCIiLCIyXG43Il0=) for 9 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
+*\=Q"(:)-
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2a%5C%3DQ%22%28%3A%29-&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A7%0A10&debug=0)

```
+*\=Q"(:)-
    Q        get input
 *\=         repeat "=" that many times
+    "(:)-   append "(:)-"
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <strike>106</strike> 103 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
void s(int n){for(int i=0;i<n;i++){std::cout<<"=";}std::cout<<"(:)-"<<std::endl;}
```

### Usage

```
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    s(length);
    return 0;
}
```

### Ungolfed

```
#include <iostream> // for printing
void outputSnake(int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { // iterates over length of snake
        std::cout << "="; // prints an equals sign
    }
    std::cout << "(:)-" << std::endl; // prints rest of snake
}
```

---

Thanks @LeakyNun for shaving off 3 bytes.

Comment: Replace `i!=n+1` with `i<n`, and I am not sure if `std::` is needed.

Comment: @LeakyNun I would have to add "using namespace std;" to remove the std portion, but i'll replace that not equal sign

Comment: Couldn't you replace the for-loop with ´while(n-->0)´?

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
:?!v"="o1-
oo;>"-):("oo
```

*-3 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun*

[Test it here.](https://www.fishlanguage.com) (you have to input the code manually)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 133 bytes

```
public class Snake {
    public void s(int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        System.out.println("(:)-");
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) site says that your code is 165 bytes.

Comment: If you prefer to just share the method then don't include the class at all, otherwise provide a main in order to provide a complete program. Anyway, class don't need to be public. Class name could be shorter. Also, you could save some bytes by concatenating the "=" and printing them all at the end.Don't include `{}` or unnecessary spaces. Here are these suggestions: http://pastebin.com/8jLNL65V

Comment: @daHugLenny I used `wc -c` on GNU/Linux to count the bytes.

Comment: Assuming tabs (because SE sites convert them to spaces) the count actually turns out to 132 bytes. (And sorry @Master_ex, it seems like LeakyNun has already used what you said in their answer so it can't be used here.)

Comment: @ValueInk, if you referring to LeakyNun's java answer (the traditional one) it seems that it was posted after my comment and in my pastebin link I save some more bytes in the for loop, but no problem, I just wanted to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <s>52</s> 36 bytes

```
while [[ ${#a} -lt $1 ]];do a=$a=;done;echo "$a(:)~"
```

```
printf -vs %$1s;echo "${s// /=}(:)~"
```

Excellent suggestion by [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87120/snakes-all-around/87139?noredirect=1#comment214156_87139).

If one would like to use external programs (sed) this could be a bit smaller(31 bytes):

```
printf "%$1s(:)~"|sed 's/ /=/g'
```

Run like that:

```
$ bash snake.sh 1
=(:)~
$ bash snake.sh 3
===(:)~
```

Comment: I would go without `while`: `printf -vs %$1s;echo "${s// /=}(:)~"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (using external library) (39 bytes)

```
n=>_.Range(0,n).Write("=",x=>"")+"(:)-"
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: Create an array of n elements, and Write a concatenated string with "=" as the delimiter and an empty string as the current element. Then concatenate the head of the snake

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Matricks](https://github.com/jediguy13/Matricks), 24 bytes

Very simple, just wanted to show off the new matrix definition feature.

```
m61:1:n;;a<40,58,41,45>;
```

Run with `python matricks.py snek.txt [[]] <input> --asciiprint`

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
61iY"'(:)-'h
```

[**Try it on MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=61iY%22%27%28%3A%29-%27h&inputs=5&version=18.6.0).

#### Explanation

```
61       % ASCII value for '='
i        % Take input number, n
Y"       % Row vector with 61 repeated n times
'(:)-'   % Push this string
h        % Concatenate horizontally. This converts to string. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```nim
import strutils,future
n=>repeat("=",n)&"(:)-"
```

This is an anonymous function that must be passed to a procedure to be used. To test, use the testing program below:

```nim
import strutils,future
proc test(f: int -> string) = echo f(#[Your input here]#)
test(n=>repeat("=",n)&"(:)-")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 35 bytes

```
#(str(apply str(repeat %\=))"(:)-")
```

This is an anonymous/unnamed function that takes a single integer as an argument and returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

### ECMAScript 6, <s>37</s> <s>44</s> [37 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#alert%28%22%3D%22.repeat%28prompt%28%29%29%20%2B%20%22%28%3A%29-%22%29%3B)

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/3aaja5xn/1/)

#### Golfed

```
alert("=".repeat(prompt())+"(:)-");
```

#### Ungolfed

```
alert("=".repeat(prompt()) + "(:)-");
```

#### Revisions

- Original revision.
- Added `alert();` because it used to save to a variable, `n`. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/3aaja5xn/)
- Used ECMAScript 6's `String.prototype.repeat` method instead of the previous method that didn't even work and took more bytes. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/3aaja5xn/1/)

---

### ECMAScript 6, [53 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#function%20makeSnakeArt%28e%29%7Balert%28%22%3D%22.repeat%28e%29%2B%22%28%3A%29-%22%29%7D)

This is a version of the above code that is a function, not a full program. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/0d01y425/1/)

#### Golfed

```
function makeSnakeArt(n){return"=".repeat(n)+"(:)-")}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
function makeSnakeArt(n) {
    return "=".repeat(n) + "(:)-"
}

alert(makeSnakeArt(5));
```

#### Revisions

- Original revision, stemming off the 3rd revision of the full program. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/0d01y425/1/)
- Returns the snake instead of alerting it. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/qas4yed3/)

Comment: @WallyWest I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: @WallyWest Why'd you delete your comment?

Answer (score 0):

### PL/SQL: 28 bytes

```
rpad('=','&n','=')||'(:)-');
```

Comment: 1) Tried it? There is no change to work due to the extra `)`. 2) No idea about the dialect, but wouldn't `lpad('(:)~',&n+4,'=');` work? 3) This is just a snippet, not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 37 bytes

```
Function S(L):S=String(L,"=")&"(:)-"
```

and `enter` gives the `End Function`. Immediate window of VBA editor:

```
?S(41)
=========================================(:)-
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 67 bytes

Code:

```
>++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+<,[->.<]<++++[>++++++++++<-]>.>---.<+.++++.
```

Explanation:

```
> At #1
++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+< Put '=' in #2
, Input into #1
[->.<] Output '=' #1 times thereby emptying #1
<++++[>++++++++++<-]>. Put '(' in #1 and output

> At #2
--- Change #2 to ':'
. Output

< At #1
+.++++. Change to '(' and 'minus' and output
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=PiBBdCAjMQorKysrKytbPisrKysrKysrKys8LV0-KzwgUHV0ICc9JyBpbiAjMgosIElucHV0IGludG8gIzEKWy0-LjxdIE91dHB1dCAnPScgIzEgdGltZXMgdGhlcmVieSBlbXB0eWluZyAjMQo8KysrK1s-KysrKysrKysrKzwtXT4uIFB1dCAnKCcgaW4gIzEgYW5kIG91dHB1dAoKPiBBdCAjMgotLS0gQ2hhbmdlICMyIHRvICc6JwouIE91dHB1dAoKPCBBdCAjMQorLisrKysuIENoYW5nZSB0byAnKCcgYW5kICdtaW51cycgYW5kIG91dHB1dA$$)

Input works using the corresponding ASCII characters - that is, to input 33 you would type `!`. For convenience, you can use `\d` as the input in the interpreter linked, where `d` is any non-negative integer.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 15 bytes

```
x->"="^x*"(:)-"
```

Wow, this is short.

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 46 bytes

```rkt
(λ(n)(string-append(make-string n#\=)"(:)-"))
```

Pretty terrible golfing language :)))

Answer (score 0):

## , 10 chars / 13 bytes

```
⍘=Ċï+'(:)-
```

<kbd>[Try it here (ES6 browsers only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%E2%8D%98%3D%C4%8A%C3%AF%2B%27(%3A)-)</kbd>

Should be rather self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

## Silicon, 12 bytes

```
I"="*"(:)-"+
```

**Explanation:**

```
I"="*"(:)-"+

    *   Times
I       Get an integer as input
"="     Push "="

"(:)-"  Push "(:)-"
+       Append
```

**Alternatively, 11 bytes:**

```
"="ã"(:)-"+
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 27 bytes

Not the most wonderfull creation, but with register_globals on you can set it via url.

```
<?=str_repeat('=',$n)?>(:)-
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```ruby
->n{puts?=*n+"(:)-"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
puts"="*($*[0].to_i)+"(:)-"
```

Comment: No need for the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 14 bytes

```
'(:)-',~'='#~]
```

Very simple. This is a five train:

```
'(:)-' ,~ '=' #~ ]
```

Both strings, in this case, become constant verbs. `#~` essentially repeats its left argument the amount of times as its right argument. `,~` then appends its left argument to the end of its right argument.

Test cases:

```
   f 2
==(:)-
   f 7
=======(:)-
   f 10
==========(:)-
   f 0
(:)-
```

I think that it would look more snake-like with a tilde at the end, but eh.

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 34 bytes

```
{String(ByteArray(it){61})+"(:)-"}
```

This assumes that a function of `(Int)->String` type is requested (in such case, `it` is assumed to be an `Int`). Version with explicit typing (40 bytes):

```
{n:Int->String(ByteArray(n){61})+"(:)-"}
```

[Try it out](http://try.kotlinlang.org/) on the JVM target:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f: (Int)->String = {String(ByteArray(it){61})+"(:)-"}
    println(f(5))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 39 bytes

Mildly different than others above

```
for(i in 1:scan())cat("=");cat("(:)-")
```

or, if we can precede the line with the input

```
->n;for(i in 1:n)cat("=");cat("(:)-")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 16 bytes

```
say'='x<>.'(:)-'
```

Takes input from stdin

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
\=*"(:)-"+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%3D%2a%22%28%3A%29-%22%2B&input=2)

Or 8 bytes (noncompeting)

```
\=*"(:)-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%3D%2a%22%28%3A%29-&input=2)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 23 bytes

```
print'='*input()+'(:)-'
```

Comment: Unless it's Python 3, you can remove the `int()` part.

Comment: @daHugLenny thanks, -5 bytes

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 24 bytes

```
def f(l) ?=*l+"(:)-";end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PyMin](https://github.com/daHugLenny/PyMin), 15 bytes

```
»"="*¬+"(:)-"
```

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 49 bytes

```
s="(:)-"for(a=0;a<argument0;a++){s="="+s}return s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org/) 34

```
[ [ "="write ] times "(:>~"print ]
```

Quotation (anonymous function) that takes a number and prints a snake.

Alternative (also 34):

```
[ 61 <string> ":>~""("glue print ]
```

<sup>Sorry, but i made some aesthetic changes...</sup>

```
10 [ [ "="write ] times "(:>~"print ] call
==========(:>~
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 15 bytes

```
{n|'=*n+"(:)-"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 28 bytes

```
I(61ai^~i)40a-8a58a32a41a+4a
```

[Try it online](http://labs.turbo.run/beta/fourier/?code=SSg2MWFpXn5pKTQwYS04YTU4YTMyYTQxYSs0YQ)

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed, 16 bytes

```sed
y/0/=/;s/$/(:)-/
```

Since sed has no native support for numbers, the input is given in unary based on this [consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary?answertab=votes#tab-top).

**Run:**

```sh
sed -f snake.sed <<< "000"
```

**Output:**

```sh
===(:)-
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 30 Bytes

```
(x:Int)=>print(("="*x)+"(:)-")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript, 14 bytes

```
ic'=P]"-):("ah
```

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript II, 13 bytes

```
"="sN*p"(:)-"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 39 bytes

```
 OUTPUT =LPAD('(:)-',INPUT + 4,'=')
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X8E/NCQgNETB1ifA0UVDXcNKU1ddx9MPJKStYKKjbquuyeXq5/L/vykA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
×=Ｎ(:)-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///wdNv3e9ZpWGnq/v9vaAAA)

This is equivalent to the following code:

```
Print(Times("=", InputNumber()));
Print("(:)-");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 20 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input, `a`, from range `[A1]` and outputs a snake of the length `a` to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
?[Rept("=",A1)]"(:)-
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX80 (4K ROM) ~39 bytes

```
 1 INPUT L
 2 FOR I=1 TO L
 3 PRINT "=";
 4 NEXT I
 5 PRINT "(:)-"
```

No explanation needed really.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 6, input unary '=', 11B

```
x=>x+'(:)-'
```

Standard rule allowes it.

Fix it if that's not what you want.

Comment: Meta seems to say for such language unary is not allowed but also say allowed. Not sure which